# Difficulty attaching an event to a programmatically created MovieClip

Tags: events, actionscript, dynamic, constructor

This has been really bugging me and I can't seem to ask the right question while searching for a solution! The problem is simple enough: Why can I not attach an event to a programmatically created MovieClip in Actionscript 3? This has got to be something basic I am missing, right?

```
package {

    //imports
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.*;

    //document class
    public class Document extends MovieClip {

        //variables
        public var utilities:Object;
        public var test:MovieClip;

        //constructor
        public function Document()
        {

            //instantiate the utilities object - this will contain some
            //simple functions for setting dimensions and background color of
            //a display object.
            this.utilities = new Object();

            //utility function: set dimensions.
            this.utilities.setDimensions = function(what:*, width:uint, height:uint)
            {
                what.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, width, height);
            }

            //utility function: set opaque background color. 
            this.utilities.setBgColor = function(what:DisplayObject, color:uint)
            {
                what.cacheAsBitmap = true; 
                what.opaqueBackground = color;
            }

            //create/add a test movie clip.
            test = new MovieClip();

            //set dimensions and background color of the test movie clip.
            this.utilities.setDimensions(test, 100, 100);
            this.utilities.setBgColor(test, 0xff0000);

            //add test movie clip to document class.
            this.addChild(test);

            //add a click event to the test movie clip.
            test.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);

        }

        //click event handler
        private function onClick(evt:Event):void
        {
            trace('click');
        }   
    }
}

//update based on Casey Yee's answer
//the set dimension function needs to contain a fill to be clickable
//a fill is added with alpha set to zero to maintain transparency.

//utility function: set dimensions 
this.utilities.setDimensions = function(what:*, width:uint, height:uint)
{
    what.graphics.beginFill(0x000000, 0);
    what.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, width, height);
    what.graphics.endFill();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

test is still a empty movie clip, try adding drawing something into it:

```
test = new MovieClip();
test.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
test.graphics.drawRect(0,0,100,100);
test.graphics.endFill();
```

Comment: Ahhh..I was assuming that drawRect actually gave the movie clip content as the test clip returns width and height and displays an opaque background color. But it is still empty without having some sort of fill? Worked like a charm though, many thanks. :o)

Comment: @Casey Yee: you could have adopt his utility functions `setDimensions` and `setBgColor` in your solution ;-)

Comment: @DanielB, yes you are right, i didn't even think to check what the functions were doing haha!

Comment: So a MovieClip with no fill has no dimensions, though still visible when drawRect and the opaqueBackground property is set. This movie clip will have height and width properties set but still not exist for click events in actionscript code? Based on all that I would have no idea what to call a combined setDimensions/setBgColor function...lol.

Comment: @Michael, you were drawing to the Document object leaving the test MovieClip completely empty.  Another thing is that if your going to be programatically drawing into the object and not require a timeline, you would be better off using Sprite instead of MovieClip.

Comment: @Casey - the setDimension function takes whatever you want to draw into as a parameter so I think I was actually drawing a rectangle where it should be. It seems like the fill is the key, which kind of makes sense as an object with no fill has nothing to click on? Maybe? Thanks again for your time and help. :o)